# Magento 2 Migration: Volume Check Failed

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I'm attempting a Magento 2 Migration on my local machine, mostly so that I have real data to work with as I learn Magento 2 (accuracy of the migration is not important).

When I run the migration tool, I get this error(s):

```
[ERROR]: Incorrect value: Freightquote_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Source_Class in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_code=freightquote_class
[ERROR]: Incorrect value: Freightquote_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Source_Packaging in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_code=freightquote_packaging
[ERROR]: Incorrect value: Freightquote_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Source_Commodity in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_code=freightquote_commodity
[ERROR]: Incorrect value: Freightquote_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Source_Content in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_code=freightquote_content
```

and ending with

```
[Migration\Exception]
Volume Check Failed
```

In the the `eav_attribute` source table (abbreviated):

```
attribute_code           | backend_type | frontend_input | source_model
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
freightquote_class       | varchar      | select         | Freightquote_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Source_Class
freightquote_packaging   | varchar      | select         | Freightquote_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Source_Packaging
freightquote_commodity   | varchar      | select         | Freightquote_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Source_Commodity
freightquote_content     | varchar      | select         | Freightquote_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Source_Content
```

I'm fine excluding this module from the migration if possible/necessary. I tried looking through the various config.xml and map.xml files for examples of how this might be handled, but couldn't really get a grasp on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized that the data in the `eav_attribute` table needed to be modified. The freightquote source models needed to be changed to be in the expected format.

So `Freightquote_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Source_Class` becomes `freightquote_shipping/carrier_source_class`. Did this for each of the rows causing an error and restarted the import. That fixed the error.

Comment: Nice :) I didn't know that the xml node for your module was "freightquote_shipping", that's why my first answer wasn't working... I corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and asked on github https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool-ce/issues/13.

You can try adding the following lines to your vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/class-map.xml.dist file :

```
<rename>
    <from>freightquote_shipping/carrier_source_class</from>
    <to />
</rename>
<rename>
    <from>freightquote_shipping/carrier_source_packaging</from>
    <to />
</rename>
<name>
    <from>freightquote_shipping/carrier_source_commodity</from>
    <to />
</rename>
<rename>
    <from>freightquote_shipping/carrier_source_content</from>
    <to />
</rename>
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, but even with correct syntax this did not work for me.

Comment: Indeed I made a mistake on the <rename> node, i just edited the post. How are declared source models in Freightquote_Shipping module ?

Comment: `class Freightquote_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Source_[Class|Packaging|Commodity|Content] extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract`

Comment: Sorry I meant how are they declared in source_model fields in your database's table "eav_attribute" ?

Comment: I included that in my original question